How do I enable the Tux logo on boot in Ubuntu Server [Without GUI]?
I wanted to have the Tux penguin logo when I boot Ubuntu Linux on my laptop server. Is there an easy way to do it?
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


Also see this Q&A
